# Handle Concurrency in Spring Controller Instance variables

Tags: java, jquery, spring, multithreading

I am using Spring 5 for a web application. Here to check whether my search query based on some inputs from html page is returning Empty value or NOT. If empty then I am showing a no Data found notification.
I have used two methods in controller for this. 
After filling the search fields I make an ajax call to the controller on button click. If data is found the controller method returns a flag which i check in the JavaScript code to check data is available or not.
If data is present then I change the attribute of form element like action to another URL and target="_blank" and make a form submit.

I have to generate a jasper report on final submit.
BUT to avoid two query hits on DATABASE , while making the first query hit on database I am storing the value to a INSTANCE VARIABLE in spring controller,
Which I am retrieving on final form submit and generating the report from the data.

I searched for answers but not getting a perfect idea how to apply in my code,
It would be of great on your part to share me with right way to implement.

******JAVA CODE*******

```
public class HrmsSalarySlipSummaryReportController {


List<Object[]> allowanceDetails;
List<Object[]> deductionDetails;` @PostMapping(value = "/reportIsEmptyCheckSal", headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<String> summaryListIsEmpty(@RequestBody HrmsSalarySlipReportDTO slipReportDTO) {
    allowanceDetails = summarySalReportServ.getAllowanceDetails(slipReportServ.getIntParameters(slipReportDTO, userSession.getUlbId()));
    deductionDetails = summarySalReportServ.getDeductionDetails(slipReportServ.getIntParameters(slipReportDTO, userSession.getUlbId()));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(summarySalReportServ.isJsonEmpty(allowanceDetails, deductionDetails));
}`
```

How to handle concurrency issue along with checking the empty returned result
Thanks.

Comment: Definitely instance variable in the controller is never the way to go (because of concurrency like you mentioned - you cannot guarantee the order in which the requests will be received by the server.).

Comment: Solving the concurrency issue (for example use a concurrent map) will not help long-term.  Making the controller state-full would require sticky sessions.  This does not scale, is not fault tolerant, and will not work in a cloud environment.  See 12 factor app for more details.  Just hit the database again, or if there is a proven need to temporarily keep the data outside the database then use a **distributed** cache so any controller instance which gets the request can find the data.

Comment: Thank you for yours valuable suggestions, but would please help me with for deciding between keeping the value of variable "allowanceDetails" in a httpSession attribute like {httpSession.setAttribute("EMPTYCHECK",allowanceDetails)} would be good or hitting the database again would be more efficient.Thank you.